# Load pretrained model on TF-Hub to calculate Word Mover's Distance (WMD) on Gensim or spaCy

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, gensim, spacy, tensorflow-hub

I'd like to calculate [Word Mover's Distance](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf) with [Universal Sentence Encoder on TensorFlow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2) embedding.

I have tried the example on [spaCy for WMD-relax](https://spacy.io/universe/project/wmd-relax), which loads 'en' model from spaCy, but I couldn't find another way to feed other embeddings.

In [gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/WMD_tutorial.ipynb), it seems that it only accepts `load_word2vec_format` file (`file.bin`) or `load` file (`file.vec`).

As I know, someone has written a [Bert to token embeddings based on pytorch](https://github.com/Kyubyong/bert-token-embeddings), but it's not generalized to other models on tf-hub.

Is there any other approach to transfer pretrained models on tf-hub to spaCy format or word2vec format?

Answer (score 0):

You need two different things.

First tell SpaCy to use an external vector for your documents, spans or tokens. This can be done by setting the  `user_hooks`:
- `user_hooks["vector"]` is for the document vector
- `user_span_hooks["vector"]` is for the span vector
- `user_token_hooks["vector"]` is for the token vector

Given the fact that you have a function that retrieves from TF Hub the vectors for a Doc/Span/Token (all of them have the property `text`):

```py
import spacy
import tensorflow_hub as hub


model = hub.load(TFHUB_URL)
def embed(element):
    # get the text
    text = element.text
    # then get your vector back. The signature is for batches/arrays
    results = model([text])
    # get the first element because we queried with just one text
    result = np.array(results)[0]
    return result
```

You can write the following pipe component, that tells spacy how to retrieve the custom embedding for documents, spans and tokens:

```py
def overwrite_vectors(doc):
    doc.user_hooks["vector"] = embed
    doc.user_span_hooks["vector"] = embed
    doc.user_token_hooks["vector"] = embed

# add this to your nlp pipeline to get it on every document
nlp = spacy.blank('en') # or any other Language
nlp.add_pipe(overwrite_vectors)
```

For your question related to the custom distance, there is a user hook also for this one:

```py
def word_mover_similarity(a, b):
    vector_a = a.vector
    vector_b = b.vector
    # your distance score needs to be converted to a similarity score
    similarity = TODO_IMPLEMENT(vector_a, vector_b)
    return similarity

def overwrite_similarity(doc):
    doc.user_hooks["similarity"] = word_mover_similarity
    doc.user_span_hooks["similarity"] = word_mover_similarity
    doc.user_token_hooks["similarity"] = word_mover_similarity

# as before, add this to the pipeline
nlp.add_pipe(overwrite_similarity)
```

I have an implementation of the TF Hub Universal Sentence Encoder that uses the `user_hooks` in this way: https://github.com/MartinoMensio/spacy-universal-sentence-encoder-tfhub

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/src-d/wmd-relax) is the implementation of WMD in spacy. You can create a WMD object and load your own embeddings:

```
import numpy
from wmd import WMD
embeddings_numpy_array = # your array with word vectors
calc = WMD(embeddings_numpy_array, ...)
```

Or, as shown in [this](https://github.com/src-d/wmd-relax/blob/master/spacy_example.py) example., you can create your own class:

```
import spacy
spacy_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

class SpacyEmbeddings(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return spacy_nlp.vocab[item].vector # here you can return your own vector instead

calc = WMD(SpacyEmbeddings(), documents)
...
...
calc.nearest_neighbors("some text")
...
```